# Why do I get future_error with async?

Tags: c++11, asynchronous, visual-c++, future

I need to start execution of vector of tasks in parallel and wait until finished. Here is how I did this, but I get future_error on MSVC. Small utility to split vector into parts:

```
template<typename T>
vector<vector<T>> split(const vector<T>& vec, size_t n) {
    vector<vector<T>> outVec;
    size_t length = vec.size() / n;
    size_t remain = vec.size() % n;
    size_t begin = 0;
    size_t end = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < std::min(n, vec.size()); ++i) {
        end += (remain > 0) ? (length + !!(remain--)) : length;
        outVec.push_back(std::vector<T>(vec.begin() + begin, vec.begin() + end));
        begin = end;
    }
    return outVec;
};
```

launch async execution:

```
template <typename T, typename R, typename F>
void execInParallel(vector<T> &tasks, vector<R> &res, F&&f, int cores) {
    function<int(int &t)> fn(std::forward<F>(f));
    auto parts = split(tasks, cores);
    vector<future<vector<R>>*> threads;
    for (auto part: parts) {
        future<vector<R>> thrd=async(launch::async, [&](vector<T> tasks) {
            vector<R> rs;
            for (auto&t : tasks) {
                rs.push_back(fn(t));
            }
            return rs;
        }, part);
        threads.push_back(&thrd);       
    }
    for (auto&thrd : threads) {
        vector<R> rs = thrd->get();
        for (auto &r : rs)
            res.push_back(r);
    }
};
```

test on stupid example:

```
int main(){
    vector<int> tasks,res;
    tasks.push_back(1);
    tasks.push_back(7);
    tasks.push_back(19);
    execInParallel(tasks,res, [&](int&t) {
        return t+8;
    }, 2);
    return 0;
}
```

May be I am inventing a bicycle? Is there anything like that in C++11 or boost out of the box? Any example available?

Comment: You have a local variable `thrd`. Then you add its address to the vector. Then the variable goes out of scope and is destroyed, leaving the pointer dangling. Finally, in the second loop your program exhibits undefined behavior by way of dereferencing a dangling pointer to an object whose lifetime has ended.

Comment: how can i fix this? If I don't use pointer, then I get error C2280

Comment: `vector<future<vector<R>>> threads; threads.push_back(std::move(thrd));`

Comment: plz put this as an answer with some hint, i'll accept the answer